# How to return a Model by name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables (Models) - Student, StudentLogs. Both tables have all the same fields named the same. except the StudentLogs table will have a DateChanged and NameChangedBy fields.

So when I update a students field - ie Name, it will write to the StudentLog table the change and who by. I have other tables like classes, teachers etc. So i need one function to log all the changes for each type (classesLog, teachersLog etc)

In my student Controller i pass the student model in to the controller in LogEntry constructor as an Object parameter. (Can I pass a Model as a parameter or is it passed as an Object?)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("StudentId, Name, Address, DOB")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(student);

            LogEntry logE = new LogEntry(_context, student, "Edit");                       
            if (logE.HasLog)
            {
                 _context.Update(studentLog); // <-- Something like this
            }

             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ...
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

I then have a separate class for performing functions such as logging entries etc. called LogEntry.cs. 
This class will take the name of the Model (Student) and iterate through other models and check for a table with Logs after the name so StudentLogs will be picked up. so it will essentially do the same for Classes, teachers etc. to see if that table exists. 
if so it will return the table to the Controller and then Update both of the Models with

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

.The LogEntry Class is something like this below

```
public class LogEntry
{
    private dbContext _context;
    private string logOperation;
    private string modelName;

    public LogEntry(dbContext Context, object Model ,string LogOperation)
    {
        _context = Context;
        logOperation= LogOperation;
        modelName += (Model.ToString().Replace("Project.Models.", "")) + "Logs";            
    }

    public bool HasLog ()
    {
        if (Type.GetType(modelName).exits??)  // <-- Not sure if possible
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Is this the best way to do it? or will I update them individually in each controller? as for Create, Edit, Delete

possibly have a function to update as well has check if there is a log table

```
public object UpdateLog ()
{              
    return Model; // return the model of the log and update it in the controller or class. not sure whats best
}
```

Comment: `DbContext.ChangeTracker` can handle all of this.  You can automate the process by overriding `SaveChangesAsync()` in your DbContext.  A log table for each entity is not a good idea.  It can be done in a single change log table for all entities.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? Some of the other tables have different columns so one table will not do.

Comment: You don't need a column-for-column mapping table to record the changes.  You can store the changed object as a JSON string with a reference to it's type and id.  You ask if this is the best way to do it and I am telling you it is not.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: I used this tutorial - https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/14/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table - and its just what I wanted, Thanks @Brad